# Generate multiple refs in map loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-ref

I am still confused if I use `useRef([]);` the right way, as `itemsRef` returns `Object {current: Array[0]}`. Here in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-platform-95qim?file=/src/App.js:0-1157

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const items = [
    {
      id: "asdf2",
      city: "Berlin",
      condition: [
        {
          id: "AF8Qgpj",
          weather: "Sun",
          activity: "Outside"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "zfsfj",
      city: "London",
      condition: [
        {
          id: "zR8Qgpj",
          weather: "Rain",
          activity: "Inside"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

  const itemsRef = useRef([]);

  // Object {current: Array[0]}
  // Why? Isn't it supposed to be filled with my refs (condition.id)
  console.log(itemsRef);

  return (
    <>
      {items.map(cities => (
        <div key={cities.id}>
          <b>{cities.city}</b>
          <br />
          {cities.condition.map(condition => (
            <div
              key={condition.id}
              ref={el => (itemsRef.current[condition.id] = el)}
            >
              Weather: {condition.weather}
              <br />
              Activity: {condition.activity}
            </div>
          ))}
          <br />
          <br />
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

In the original example I receive `// Object {current: Array[3]}` when I `console.log(itemsRef);` The difference is that I used in my version `itemsRef.current[condition.id]` as its a nested map loop and therefore `i` doesn't work.

```
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const items = ["sun", "flower", "house"];
  const itemsRef = useRef([]);

  // Object {current: Array[3]}
  console.log(itemsRef);

  return items.map((item, i) => (
    <div key={i} ref={el => (itemsRef.current[i] = el)}>
      {item}
    </div>
  ));
}
```

Comment: Thats certainly not the correct way, whats your end goal to happen ? 

you might want to create a functional component for weather activity, Map that component with condition as props, use `useRef` inside that component to reference the `div`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using non-numeric string keys when adding the `refs` to `itemRefs`, which means they end up being properties of the array object, but not *array elements*, so its length remains `0`. Depending on your console, it may or may not show non-element properties on an array object.

You could make them array elements instead by using the `index` from `map` (but keep reading!):

```
{cities.condition.map((condition, index) => (
    <div
        key={condition.id}
        ref={el => (itemsRef.current[index] = el)}
    >
        Weather: {condition.weather}
        <br />
        Activity: {condition.activity}
    </div>
))}
```

**but** depending on what you're doing with those refs I would avoid that in favor of making each `condition` its own component instead:

```
const Condition = ({weather, activity}) => {
    const itemRef = useRef(null);
  
    return (
        <div
            ref={itemRef}
        >
            Weather: {weather}
            <br />
            Activity: {activity}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Then get rid of `itemRefs` and do:

```
{cities.condition.map(({id, weather, activity}) => (
    <Condition key={id} weather={weather} activity={activity} />
))}
```

One problem with your current way even if we use array elements is that `itemRefs` will continue to have three elements in it even when the DOM elements that they used to refer to are gone (they'll have `null` instead), since React calls your `ref` callback with `null` when the element is removed, and your code is just storing that `null` in the array.

Alternatively, you might use an object:

```
const itemRefs = useRef({});
// ...
{cities.condition.map(condition => (
    <div
        key={condition.id}
        ref={el => {
            if (el) {
                itemsRef.current[condition.id] = el;
            } else {
                delete itemsRef.current[condition.id];
            }
        }}
    >
        Weather: {condition.weather}
        <br />
        Activity: {condition.activity}
    </div>
))}
```

Or perhaps a `Map`:

```
const itemRefs = useRef(new Map());
// ...
{cities.condition.map(condition => (
    <div
        key={condition.id}
        ref={el => {
            if (el) {
                itemsRef.current.set(condition.id, el);
            } else {
                itemsRef.current.delete(condition.id);
            }
        }}
    >
        Weather: {condition.weather}
        <br />
        Activity: {condition.activity}
    </div>
))}
```

But again, I'd lean toward making a `Condition` component that manages its own ref.

Comment: Hey, could you tell me why are you checking for `el` in case of an object or map?

Comment: @Siddharth - See [Callback Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs). As I mentioned above, when the DOM element is removed, React calls the callback with `null`. So the code above branches in order to remove the entry for the element entirely (rather than just setting it `null`).

Comment: Thanks a lot T.J. Crowder for the good answers. Especially your last suggestion with Map was very helpful as I found a package earlier that seems to have the same approach with Map: https://github.com/Macil/react-multi-ref/blob/master/src/index.js 

I am not sure yet if the `Condition` component approach works for my case. I will try if I can rearrange my code. Here you can see my intended use for the `ref`: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-cherry-42tin?file=/src/Parent.js